# Looping If condition in formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

[image: Spreadsheet]
Hi, I want to find the value of column A when the Value of E first goes to zero. In above table the value of A column would be 47 as it is the first instance when the E value in same row is 0. I tried the IF function

```
=IF(AND(E1:E100=0,E2:E99<>0),A1:A100,0)
```

But this doesnt work. I cannot find out on how to loop through each row or use any index.

Edits:

1. I am looking for an excel way to do it and not using VBA.
2. I am inserting the value at the bottom of the table which shows the value of A where does E becomes zero

Comment: Are you looking for Excel Worksheet formula or VBA solution? Also, in which column did you put that formula? Please clarify your question. Best Regards,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple `INDEX(MATCH(...))` pair should take care of this handily.

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(A:A, MATCH(0, E:E, 0)), "no zero found in E")
```

I've used full column references but I don't think that should adversely affect performance on the lookup unless many lookups of this nature were used and matches were not found.

Comment: Not only _should (not) adversely affect performance_, whole column references are just as fast. ([Tested using method form here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff700515%28v=office.14%29.aspx))